# ora 00907 missing right parenthesis create table

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

Why is it giving the error when the syntax is correct? I have tried to do it without foreign key & constraint, but it still doesn't work

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET
(
    Tid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Price INT NOT NULL,
    Cid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Tid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ticket_cid
    FOREIGN KEY (Cid)
    REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Cid)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - just remove `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Since, Oracle does not have `"ON UPDATE CASCADE"`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=613ea3f61384876f557215c136a2c9ba)

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET
(
    Tid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Price INT NOT NULL,
    Cid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Tid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ticket_cid
    FOREIGN KEY (Cid)
    REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Cid)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```